# Regular expression for comma separated string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a pattern in Java that matches the following string;

```
String message ="%%140911,A,140929100526,S0117.6262E03647.8107,000,067,F100,4F000100,108";
```

The pattern I have formed is not matching the string. What am I missing? Ihis is my pattern what I tried so far:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(

       "(\\%\\%)"+"(\\d)," + // Id 
       "([AL])," + // Validity a for valid and l for invalid
       "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})," + // Date (YYMMDD)Time (HHMMSS)
       "([NS])" + "(\\d{2})(\\d{2}\\.\\d+)" + "([EW])" + "(\\d{3})(\\d{2}\\.\\d+)," + //loc 
       "(\\d+)," + // Speed
       "(\\d+)," + // Direction
       "([FC])" + "(\\d{3})," + // temperature in Fahrenheit/celsius
       "(\\w{8})," + // status
       "(\\d+)"); // event
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Simply split the string by comma and assign it in different variables.

Comment: wanted to match a message sent to the server to the specific pattern but also have an option of just splitting the string

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `+` in first line. Try changing

```
"(\\%\\%)"+"(\\d),"
```

to

```
"(\\%\\%)"+"(\\d+),"
```

Comment: Good catch. BTW, @user3737364, when you write regular expression try to start from something simple and then make it more complicated. If complex regex does not work, simplify it until it starts working. In this case it was a luck that your bug appears in the very beginning of your regex. But probably there are more bugs and it is very difficult to see them in so complex expression.

Comment: you don't need to escape `%`